# Powershell: compare and match specific part of filename

Tags: powershell, script

I have something want to use Powershell to write. Could anyone know it? Thanks.
I use powershell to create a list.
e.g.

`$SUID = @("0011", "0012", "0013", "0014", "0015")`

I have a folder containing log files:

```
0010Log201811151440.log
0012Log201811151440.log
0013Log201811151440.log
0017Log201811151440.log
0015Log201811151440.log
```

I want to use Powershell to determine SUID and files matching. Such as:

```
0011 = file is missing
0012 = 0012Log201811151440.log
0013 = 0013Log201811151440.log
0014 = file is missing
0015 = 0015Log201811151440.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a split method to get the first part of the name:

```
$filename = "0010Log201811151440.log"
$separator = "Log"
$first = ($filename -split $separator)[0]
$first
```

Comment: Dear Xaero Walk.

Thanks, this is very useful to split first 4 number. I'm thinking how to split ~70 logs of filename and get first 4 number of each filename. Thanks.

Best regards,
Ken